# Alternatives for a LEFT OUTER JOIN query

Tags: sql-server, join, h2

### Problem

I have a SQL statement with an `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which works fine on our `Microsoft SQL Server`. My problem is that i have to be compatible with `H2 Database` and this one got a bug with `OUTER JOINS`.

---

### SQL Query

```
SELECT *
FROM tSysNls
WHERE nlsGuid IN
    ( SELECT nlsGuid = CASE 
    WHEN de_AT.nlsGuid IS NOT NULL THEN de_AT.nlsGuid 
    WHEN de.nlsGuid IS NOT NULL THEN de.nlsGuid ELSE en.nlsGuid 
    END
    FROM tSysNLS en
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tSysNLS de ON en.nlsAttribute=de.nlsAttribute
        AND en.nlsClazz=de.nlsClazz
        AND de.nlsLocale= 'de'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tSysNLS de_AT ON de.nlsAttribute=de_AT.nlsAttribute
        AND de.nlsClazz=de_AT.nlsClazz
        AND de_AT.nlsLocale= 'de_AT'
    WHERE en.nlsLocale= 'en'
        AND en.nlsClazz= 'Contact'
        AND en.nlsAttribute= 'firstName')
```

---

### Table

```
CREATE TABLE tsysNLS
(
   nlsGuid           nvarchar(207)   NOT NULL,
   nlsLocale         nvarchar(5)     NOT NULL,
   nlsClazz          nvarchar(100)   NOT NULL,
   nlsAttribute      nvarchar(100)   NOT NULL,
   nlsDisplayName    nvarchar(255)   NOT NULL,
   nlsOldname        nvarchar(50),
   nlsDescription    nvarchar(255),
   nlsShapefilename  nvarchar(10)
);
```

---

### Example data

```
INSERT INTO tsysNLS(nlsGuid, nlsLocale, nlsClazz, nlsAttribute, nlsDisplayName, nlsOldname, nlsDescription, nlsShapefilename)
VALUES(N'Contact.firstName.en', N'en', N'Contact', N'firstName', N'Name - First Name', N'conFirstName', N'Name - First Name', NULL);
INSERT INTO tsysNLS(nlsGuid, nlsLocale, nlsClazz, nlsAttribute, nlsDisplayName, nlsOldname, nlsDescription, nlsShapefilename)
VALUES(N'Contact.firstName.de', N'de', N'Contact', N'firstName', N'Vorname', N'conFirstName', NULL, N'ConNamVor');
INSERT INTO tsysNLS(nlsGuid, nlsLocale, nlsClazz, nlsAttribute, nlsDisplayName, nlsOldname, nlsDescription, nlsShapefilename)
VALUES(N'Contact.firstName.de_AT', N'de_AT', N'Contact', N'firstName', N'Vorname (AT)', N'conFirstName', NULL, N'ConNamVor');
```

Comment: You can always rewrite outer joins with `UNION` and some `NOT EXISTS` subqueries - but it's going to be a much longer (in code) query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

this is *not* exactly what i asked for but it solves the problem of the original query to fail on `H2 Database`
thanks [ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube) your suggestion is correct

```
SELECT *
FROM tSysNls
WHERE nlsGuid IN
    ( SELECT CASE 
    WHEN de_AT.nlsGuid IS NOT NULL THEN de_AT.nlsGuid 
    WHEN de.nlsGuid IS NOT NULL THEN de.nlsGuid ELSE en.nlsGuid 
    END AS nlsGuid
    FROM tSysNLS en
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tSysNLS de ON en.nlsAttribute=de.nlsAttribute
        AND en.nlsClazz=de.nlsClazz
        AND de.nlsLocale= 'de'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tSysNLS de_AT ON de.nlsAttribute=de_AT.nlsAttribute
        AND de.nlsClazz=de_AT.nlsClazz
        AND de_AT.nlsLocale= 'de_AT'
    WHERE en.nlsLocale= 'en'
        AND en.nlsClazz= 'Contact'
        AND en.nlsAttribute= 'firstName')
```

results in a correct result.

but due (lot) better performance i process the whole table to Objects in my Application now and grab the Objects (select which one is the right one by code)

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite the `LEFT JOIN` to a subquery, but it may still *compile* as an outer join query - I have no knowledge of those aspects of the H2 platform.

```
SELECT *
FROM tSysNls
WHERE nlsGuid IN (
    SELECT COALESCE(
           --- first option:
           (SELECT de_AT.nlsGuid
            FROM tSysNLS AS de_AT
            WHERE de_AT.nlsClazz=x.nlsClazz AND
                  de_AT.nlsAttribute=en.nlsAttribute AND
                  de_AT.nlsLocale='de_AT'),
           --- second option:
           (SELECT de.nlsGuid
            FROM tSysNLS AS de
            WHERE de.nlsClazz=x.nlsClazz AND
                  de.nlsAttribute=en.nlsAttribute AND
                  de.nlsLocale='de'),
           --- third option:
           en.nlsGuid)
    FROM tSysNLS AS en
    WHERE en.nlsLocale='en'
        AND en.nlsClazz='Contact'
        AND en.nlsAttribute='firstName');
```

Or you could build some type of temp table (or a regular table if H2 doesn't support temp tables), then populate it in three steps. Again, this will probably still *compile* using an anti-semijoin or some other type of outer join, but maybe it'll function as a workaround for your bug:

```
--- 1. de_AT, if there are any:
INSERT INTO #temptable SELECT * FROM tSysNls
WHERE nlsLocale='de_AT' AND nlsClazz='Contact' AND nlsAttribute='firstName';

--- 2. de for those that don't have de_AT:
INSERT INTO #temptable SELECT * FROM tSysNls
WHERE nlsLocale='de' AND nlsClazz='Contact' AND nlsAttribute='firstName'
      AND nlsGuid NOT IN (SELECT nlsGuid FROM #temptable);

--- 3. en for the remaining records:
INSERT INTO #temptable SELECT * FROM tSysNls
WHERE nlsLocale='en' AND nlsClazz='Contact' AND nlsAttribute='firstName'
      AND nlsGuid NOT IN (SELECT nlsGuid FROM #temptable);

SELECT * FROM #temptable;
```

But these are not pretty solutions.

Answer (score -4):

i had two queries without outer join, which worked fast and correct on `Microsoft SQL Server` but both did not work out on `H2 Database`
one of em because `MSSQL` uses **+** to concatenate strings and `H2` uses **CONCAT** (which is crap because afaik this does not match the SQL specifications)

my final solution is to create one single query in my code and find the correct stuff with code.

---

One of the queries i tried was this one (works on `Microsoft SQL Server` but not on H2 due different concatenate syntax)

---

```
SELECT * FROM tSysNLS
WHERE nlsGuid = CASE
WHEN exists(select * from tSysNLS where nlsClazz = ?4 and nlsAttribute = ?5 and nlsLocale = ?2) then ?4+'.'+?5+'.'+?2
WHEN exists(select * from tSysNLS where nlsClazz = ?4 and nlsAttribute = ?5 and nlsLocale = ?1) then ?4+'.'+?5+'.'+?1
ELSE ?4+'.'+?5+'.'+?3
END
```

where ?# are parameters
**?1** = 'de_AT'
**?2** = 'de'
**?3** = 'en'
**?4** = 'Contact'
**?5** = 'firstName'

Comment: H2 also uses `||` which is the standard SQL concatenation operator, as others have mentioned in the comments. If `CONCAT()` is crap, then so must `+` be because that is proprietary as well (to SQL-Server). The `alias = expression` syntax is also SQL-Server only. I suppose that's why you were getting those errors and not due to some bug.

Comment: Also in an answer, it's usual to include a working query, a solution, not one that doesn't work.

Comment: including a query makes sense iff there is a query used. `select * from tsysnls` <- ther you go. hope you are happy now.

Comment: Sorry but no. Your question had several flaws and I was hoping the answer would remedy them. But the answer failed to admit that there was no bug found in H2SQL's implementation of outer joins. It fails to admit that the differences in SQL syntax between SQL-Server, H2SQL and the standard (that you claim to try following) was the source of the problems. You failed to provide code that works and is equivalent to the code in the question. And the only thing in the answer that looked like an answer (that you used as a workaround 1-3 queries depending on the data) was removed in the last edit.

Comment: my question was a problem with a query for TWO different servers MSSQL 2000 and H2. I did not find a bug because its already known! i did never say that my question is SQL standard nor that it is perfect. it was the query that was used on mssql2000. i removed the last query as you requested MY ANSWER/ Solution, which is finally different to what i wrote before. i do not know what you mean by 'flaws' in my question. but actually i do not longer want to know it as you seem to search for someone to flame. so leave it that way.

Comment: Sorry if my message sounded insulting. I did not mean it that way. You claim a known bug but you haven't shown a link to a page that describes the bug. Or a very simple demonstration (here is the code, here is the error message from H2). Then people would believe you hit a bug.

Comment: My very first question from yesterday was *"What is the bug? Do you get an error?"* which was not answered. (But you are right, I shouldn't have said "flaws", not a very good description. Perhaps "omissions". English is not my native language.)

Comment: It seems there *is* (or *was*) a bug with outer joins, specifically with *right* outer joins, in H2 according to information on [this page](http://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html#known_bugs). Note that apart from the fact that the issue was not with *left* outer joins, it also says there the bug was fixed in version 1.3, and, based on [this](http://www.h2database.com/html/download.html), the latest version appears to be 1.4. Now, you said earlier that H2 was your choice. Did you happen to choose to use an old version of it?

Comment: i'm running `H2 Version 1.4.181 (2014-08-06), Beta` and no errors get reported. the result of the query is just empty...

Comment: @lumo, did you try changing that `nlsGuid = CASE ... END` syntax to `CASE ... END AS nlsGuid`? That may be the cause of that. (H2 interpreting the `=` as a condition so the results of the subquery would be TRUE and FALSE values.)

Comment: this one does work indeed!